# Doing threading with sqlalchemy properly?

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

I have a multi threaded application where the treads work on some objects fetched using sqlalchemy. The objects are put in a thread queue which the threads poll from.

In the main thread I am doing this:

```
feeds = db_session.query(Feed).filter(Feed.last_checked <= int(update_time)).all()
for feed in feeds:
    self.feed_q.put(feed)
```

And in the threads I do some updates to the feed objects, and I keep getting these exceptions sometimes when doing updates:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now") 
StatementError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back (original cause: InvalidRequestError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back)
```

I understand that this has something todo with the threads sharing the same DB session, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit on what you're doing with multiple threads.  How you are using your objects, and the kinds of things you'd like to do with them may determine the best way to make your program work well with threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each thread should have a separate database session. You're probably creating the object that's eventually stored in `db_session` somewhere, perhaps like this:

```
db_session = Session()
```

Essentially, you need each thread to have its own `db_session`.

Comment: How do I register the object that is put to the queue with the session created in the thread then?

Comment: @pyCtrl_: Run `db_session.expunge(feed)` on the main thread before sending it off and `db_session.add(feed)` on the worker thread.